# Filter results further based on pattern

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, we are able to successfully extract lines we need from doc.

Code:

```
Get-Content "C:\Contract.doc" | 
    Select-String -Pattern "in relation to any Facility" | 
    Select -Property @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$_.Line}}
```

Output:

```
Name
----
in relation to any Facility A Loan [2% ] per cent. per annum;
in relation to any Facility B Loan [ 5% ] per cent. per annum;
```

What we are looking for is extract 2% ... 5% from the above output

Code, we are trying is not working for us:

```
Get-Content "C:\Contract.doc" | 
    Select-String -Pattern "in relation to any Facility" | 
    Select -Property @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$_.Line}} |
    Select-String '\[\?+([^?]+)\?+\]' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

Can anyone please help how to extract like below:

```
"in relation to any Facility A Loan [2% ] per cent. per annum", "2%"
```

Part of Word Doc: Contract doc

```
"Margin" means:
(a) in relation to any Facility A Loan [2% ] per cent. per annum;
(b) in relation to any Facility B Loan [ 5% ] per cent. per annum;
(c) [in relation to any Incremental Facility Loan, the percentage rate per annum specified as such in the Incremental Facility Notice relating to the Incremental Facility under which that Incremental Facility Loan is made or is to be made;]
```

Comment: Please also provide (part of) the contents of `C:\Contract.doc`.

Comment: added contract portion

Comment: In light of your previous question: is it always percentages in square brackets that you want to extract, or other substrings as well? What differentiates the substrings you want to extract from those you don't want extracted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**EDIT:**

```
$FinalTable = Get-Content .\Contract.doc |
        select-string -pattern "in relation to any Facility" |
        Select -Property @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$_.Line}} |
        ForEach-Object {
        $str = $_.Name
        $start = $str.indexOf("[") + 1
        $end = $str.indexOf("]", $start)
        $length = $end - $start

        $result = ($str.substring($start, $length)).trim()

        #Creating a custom object to display in table format
        $Obj = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $str
        Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Value -Value $result

        $obj
    }
    $FinalTable
```

Comment: Excellent, gets the value i was looking for. How can we display like this pls:

" in relation to any Facility A Loan [2% ] per cent. per annum;", 2%

Comment: Made changes. All you have to do is create a custom object and put the items you want in it as properties of it.

Answer (score 3):

Check on the next snippet.

```
Get-Content C:\Contract.doc |
Select-String -Pattern @'
\b(in relation to any Facility [A-Z] Loan \[\s*(\d+%)\s*\] per cent. per annum);
'@ |
Select-Object @{Name = 'Line'; Expression = {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}},
              @{Name = 'Result'; Expression = {$_.Matches.Groups[2].Value}}
```

To get an explanation of the regex `\b(in relation to any Facility [A-Z] Loan \[\s*(\d+%)\s*\] per cent. per annum);`, please click [here](https://regex101.com/r/WUEnNc/1).

Answer (score 1):

With a [Regular Expression](https://regex101.com/r/sPwG39/1) the solution is more efficient:

```
Get-Content .\contract.doc|
  Where-Object {$_ -match 'in relation to any Facility.*\[([\d% ]+)\]'}| 
    ForEach-Object{
      [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name  = $_
        Value = $Matches[1].trim()
      }
    }
```

And I really should scroll down before posting a similar answer.